# Displaying single search with multiple *ngFor angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I created a search to filter out the data .

After accomplishing that, I encounter a problem such as when displaying the results, it will return together with the header .

I am trying to get rid of the header after data is key in...

Please see the images below as for better understanding 
[image]

As For my codes in my html page. I feel that i have to adjust somewhere here. Do i have to use ngIf instead ?

```
    <h2>41 New Icons</h2> 

    <div *ngFor="let item of _faData | filter: filterText" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" [hidden]="item.hidden">
        <i class="fa {{item.text}}"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Example of </span>{{item.text}}
    </div> 
    <br>
    <hr>



        <h2>Web Application Icons</h2> 

    <div *ngFor="let item of _faDataWeb | filter: filterText" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" [hidden]="item.hidden">
        <i class="fa {{item.text}}"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Example of </span>{{item.text}}
    </div> 

        <hr>
```

as for my array in ts file, i just declared it as

```
  private _faData : Array<any> = [
  {..}
  {..}
  ];
```

Comment: What's the problem? `I am trying to get rid of the header after data is key in` .. what? :)

Comment: when i filter out,  it is not suppose to display the header e.g( web application icons & New icons)that can be seen inside my html file. . instead , it is only suppose to display the icons when use key in something in the filter seach bar.  but i am writting multiple ngfor. hence , i am not so sure how can i adjust code this out.